# Setup projects referencing old resources in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference, resources

I have a setup project in Visual Studio 2008 which is supposed to install my application along with SQL Express 2008.

If I locally debug my app, I can see the about and splash screen for the actual version (2.2), but if I build the setup project or the solution itself, then when I run the installer, I can see the old splash and about screen, just like it was referencing to the old resources, somewhere, because those old .BMP files don't exist anymore in my directory.

Do any of you guys know where this can be changed and why?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it: I just removed the *Primary Ouput* reference from my setup project and added it again. Problem solved :)